# Where does the floating point error come from? (Finite difference using matrix multiplication versus shifts and adding.)

Tags: floating-point, julia

In Julia it appears that one picks up some error terms when doing finite differences using matrix multiplication versus shifts and addition.

```
julia> n = 1000
1000

julia> hessM = circshift(eye(n),-1) + circshift(eye(n),1) - 2* eye(n);

julia> function hess(x::Vector)
         return circshift(x,-1) + circshift(x,1) - 2*x
       end
hess (generic function with 1 method)

julia> x = rand(n);

julia> maximum(hessM * x - hess(x))
0.0

julia> x = rand(n)/300;

julia> maximum(hessM * x - hess(x))
8.673617379884035e-19
```

I understand that this is floating point error, since if I do `x = rand(n) / 256` (or any power of 2 for that matter) the error goes away, but if we divide by something as simple as 3 the error crops up.

But where exactly is the floating point error coming in when running the above code? And why is it sensitive to the division?

---

Edit: in fact, I have localized the difference to

```
julia> x = rand(n)/3;

julia> maximum(hessM * x + 2 * eye(n) * x - circshift(eye(n),-1) * x - circshift(eye(n),1)*x)
1.1102230246251565e-16

julia> x = rand(n);

julia> maximum(hessM * x + 2 * eye(n) * x - circshift(eye(n),-1) * x - circshift(eye(n),1)*x)
0.0

julia> x = rand(n) * 3;

julia> maximum(hessM * x + 2 * eye(n) * x - circshift(eye(n),-1) * x - circshift(eye(n),1)*x)
8.881784197001252e-16
```

What gives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Edit (July 2021)***: it appears that the behavior will be changed as a side effect of the move of the default PRNG from Mersenne Twister to Xoshiro in the 1.7 release of Julia. See comments below.

---

It seems that this is tied to how Julia generates random numbers; I've [opened a discussion on the Julia Language site](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/16344). The current implementation of Julia's random number generator for the default range `[0,1)` for floats (in other words, calling simply `rand()`) always produces a `0` in the least significant bit for some reason or another (unlike MATLAB, for example). A side effect of this is that floating point errors are suppressed (since these are often errors coming from rounding/cancellation to the lowest bit). Multiplying/dividing by a power of 2 do not change the significand in the floating point representation, however multiplying/dividing by a non-power does. So generically after multiplying/dividing by some non-power, the least significant bit can be either 1 or zero, and now floating point error occurs as usually expected.

Comment: Note that this will change soon since for Google Summer of Code there is a project to create [RNG.jl](https://github.com/sunoru/RNG.jl) which implements a bunch of RNGs, and use the best one to replace the current RNG.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Any idea what the status of this is now? Running the code in Julia 1.6 (replacing `eye` with an appropriate `diagm` call), I get the same results as in the question. Is there a place where there's either ongoing discussion or documentation, regarding this?

Comment: There's https://github.com/JuliaRandom/RandomNumbers.jl, https://github.com/JuliaRandom/StableRNGs.jl, and Julia Base just changed its RNG in Julia v1.7: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/40546

Comment: By chance, I _just_ finished installed Julia 1.7-beta2. Testing in it, the error with `rand(n)/300` returns the same value, and now the error with just `rand(n)` is also non-zero: `2.220446049250313e-16`. Serendipitous that I came across this five-year old question right around the time the fix is to be released. :)